# how to implement a comet server by tornado？

Tags: python, tornado

I know how to implment a Simple comet server。
but I want to ask:
Is there any good open source code ？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [tornadio2](https://github.com/MrJoes/tornadio2) project, which implements socket.io support for tornado.